# VBA change instance variable from module (excel)

Tags: excel, vba, variables, module, instance

In VBA I need a module sub to tell an instance to set up some variables.

In Module 1 I have:

```
Sub Load()
ThisWorkbook.SetupVariables
ThisWorkbook.TestVariables
End Sub
```

In ThisWorkbook I have:

```
Private Variable1 As Integer
Private Variable2 As String
Private Variable3 As MyUserDefinedObjectType

Public Sub SetupVariables()
Variable1 = 5
Variable2 = "Five"
Set Variable3 = New MyUserDefinedObjectType()
End Sub

Sub TestVariables()
MsgBox Variable1 & " is spelled " & Variable2
Variable3.SomeFunction
End Sub
```

The call to TestVariables inside Load() yields the correct result, but subsequent calls to TestVariables fail. How can I make Variable1 and Variable2 hold their values? (In my real-world situation, these variables are objects I've defined and cannot be made public variables.)

Sequence of events:

`Load` is stored in `Module1` and is associated with a form button on `Worksheet1`. This is pressed first.

Subsequently, an ActiveX control in `Worksheet2` tells `ThisWorkbook` to call `TestVariables`.

Comment: Why are you calling it using `ThisWorkbook. ... ` ? Why not directly call it?

Comment: I need these variables to stay in scope after the "Load" sub completes its execution. I'm hiding all my private variables in ThisWorkbook and instead providing accessor/mutator functions to get to them.

Comment: Something else is going on which isn't shown in the code you posted. Are you doing anything in other code which might reset the VBA environment? Like calling `End` for example?

Comment: No, I haven't called `End`. I just hit the form button (stored in `Module1`) on `Worksheet1` for `Load()`, then hit a form button in `Worksheet2` (stored in `Worksheet2`) that tells `ThisWorkbook` to call its `TestVariables()` subroutine. Since the variables are all kept in `ThisWorkbook` I'd expect them to keep, but they're all freshly initialized when I check after `Load()`.

Comment: Actually, `Load()` is called by a form button in `Module1`, the button in `Worksheet2` is really an ActiveX control. (So the ActiveX tells `ThisWorkbook` to call `TestVariables`)

Comment: What's the exact behavior you see when you make a later call to `TestVariables` ?  You say the calls "fail" but don't mention exactly **how** they fail.

Comment: Since the code you posted should work (and others have tested it successfully) can you upload a workbook which demonstrates the issue you're having?  I think at this point we're mostly just guessing what else is going on.

Comment: @Tim: Sorry, that was vague. The return value treats the variables like they've been freshly initialized. (i.e. 0, false, Nothing, etc.)

Comment: The actual code is HUGE, so there's no hope for posting that. However, if you can point me towards potential issues, I can include relevant portions.

Comment: Are you programmatically editing code within the workbook?  That can cause a recompile...

Comment: ... or adding OLEObjects to a worksheet?  Really I have no other guesses.

Comment: I'm doing both of those things. Is there any way to hold onto an object after programmatically editing code and adding OLEObjects?

Comment: I don't suppose there's a builtin way to export an instance and everything it references to storage or some memory location that it won't be lost?

Comment: Are there any objects I could pass these to that would survive the recompile?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as you have it.  Create a Watch (View - Watch Window) for Variable1 and choose Break When Value Changes.  You should be able to see when it changes to zero.

Comment: Sadly I can't touch breakpoints in my program because I'm changing resources. (Moving worksheets, etc.)

Comment: Are you setting the values with one formbutton and checking them with a second one, or is this all running off one button?

Comment: Is it possible something I'm doing is causing the instance of ThisWorkbook to get killed and a new one gets created?