# VBA preserve instances after macro completes (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel, scope, instance

I have some objects of my own that I instantiate inside `ThisWorkbook` in Excel. I'm having [some trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365758/vba-change-instance-variable-from-module-excel) and I think the issue is that VBA is killing my instances as soon as the macro ends.

We're using `ThisWorkbook`:

- If I define my own variable for `ThisWorkbook` in a macro, that variable's value is back to the initialization value after the macro completes, even if the variable is Dim'd in the class of `ThisWorkbook` and not in the module. (i.e. 0, Nothing, etc.)
- If I instantiate an object for `ThisWorkbook` in the `Workbook_Open()` event, the object is destroyed when the event is done firing. Again, even if the variable is Dim'd in the class of `ThisWorkbook` and not in the sub for `Workbook_Open()`

Is there something I can do to make sure these objects survive and these variables retain their values?

In `ThisWorkbook`:

```
'Object we want to survive
Dim myInstance As MyObject

Private Sub Open_Workbook()
    Set myInstance = new MyObject ' Object is instantiated
End Sub

' Macro 1
Public Sub MyMacro()
    Set myInstance = new MyObject ' Object is instantiated
End Sub

' Macro 2
Public Sub CheckInstance()
    If Not myInstance is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "I found an instance!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Neither opening the workbook nor running Macro 1 will cause Macro 2 to find myInstance. In both cases, Macro2 will think that myInstance is Nothing. Macro 2 will ONLY find myInstance if it's called inside Macro 1 or Open_Workbook (before their End Sub). I need a fix for this. (I'm running these macros from separate form buttons, NOT inside some other macro.)

Comment: How about if you make it a public variable?  And define it in another module.  I should know offhand if this will help, but I don't.

Comment: Presume it's a typo here but you have `Open_Workbook()` in your code instead of `Workbook_Open()`

Comment: Can't make it a public variable, 'cause it's a user-defined object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to create variables outside of your macros.

Otherwise they will be always destroyed with the end of the macro.

```
'will be available as long the file is open
Private lngTest as long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
    'will be available as long as routine is running   
    Dim lngTest2 as long
    lngTest = lngTest + 1
    lngTest2 = lngTest2 + 1

    debug.print lngTest
    debug.print lngTest2
End Sub
```

Because you were talking about `Workbook_Open` - to save your variables, even through closing and reopening a workbook, you would need another construct. My suggestion would be storing them in Worksheets, but I belive there are other methods too.

*Edit:*

Tested your posted code with this - works fine, finds instance.

MyObject as a class:

```
Private lngTest As Long

Public Property Get test() As Long
    test = lngTest
End Property

Public Property Let test(ByVal lngValue As Long)
    lngTest = lngValue
End Property
```

Comment: I'm working with a variable pointing to an instance of an object. I Dim'd the variable to the object outside the `Worksheet_Open()` sub, I only instantiate it inside `Worksheet_Open()`, so it has class scope, and should be surviving. But... As soon as `Worksheet_Open()` finishes firing, the `Instance_Destroy()` fires for the object I've instantiated. (I set `Instance_Destroy()` to shoot me a `MsgBox` so I could be sure.) I encourage you to independently verify this.

Comment: @geofurb - ok, I am guessing this is about your UserDefinedType - have you tried to make the new statement outside of the macro? `Private Variable3 As new MyUserDefinedObjectType`? Have to use you a bit for debug, can't find my examples that quick ...

Comment: I need to instantiate the object in my macro, but I need for it to persist after the macro finishes firing.

Comment: @geofurb as Tim Williams already said in your other question, there seems something to be missing here. Based on what you presented, I at least cannot see, where the problem is. BUT there might be problems based on your UDT/Class, depending on its structure. Maybe you should let us in on the whole picture - except of course your last exampled does not work, with my simplyfied object, like it did for me.

Comment: I can't provide the entire code, but if you can suggest possible problems that could give me these symptoms, I can provide relevant sections of the code.

Comment: the most important question would be, if this example of yours does not work at all or just not with your specific custom object.

Comment: There are two such objects, and it does not seem to work with either of them. One is more or less just a dumbed-down collection class tailored to fit my needs. (I didn't actually implement the Collection interface or extend any existing Collection.)

Comment: I think something I'm doing in manipulating the environment must be killing the instances I set up. I assumed that things got reset at the end of a form button's macro, but that must be incorrect. What really puzzles me is that objects created in Workbook_Open() die instantly. Is that not the case for you? (Assuming said objects are stored in the workbook, not in the event sub.)

Comment: My point was, if you use my example class - does it work then? We need to have common ground here - and as of right now, from my point of view, this stuff already works. And no, objects created in Workbook_Open() do not die instantly, at least common objects don't, if they are defined outside of the function.

Comment: Tim seems to have found the issue: I'm recompiling at runtime (programmatically adding code and OLEObjects) so everything gets flushed. Any way to export the instance of an object (and every instance it references) to disk or a safe location in memory?

Comment: Are there any objects I can pass these to that would survive a recompile?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new module for the project in the VBA editor (`Module1`), and insert this code:

```
Dim testVar As Integer

Sub Test()
    testVar = testVar + 1
    MsgBox testVar
End Sub
```

Then add a row to for example the Worksheet's Activate or the Open event:

```
Module1.Test
```

It worked for me, the value was incrementing each time I activated the sheet.

Comment: Try instantiating an object (declared in the class) in Workbook_Open(). For the destructor of that object, set up a MsgBox. The MsgBox will fire as soon as the Workbook_Open() event completes.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365758/vba-change-instance-variable-from-module-excel for the reason I'm having this problem.

Comment: @ImreGreilich thank you so much. What if I don't want the value incremented each time - how can i stop it doing that? any help/advice would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

why not trying to use array? You dim it out of your macros and it will keep the data until you clear it with another macro or shoot the workbook off.